# Regex match between two regex expressions

Tags: regex

This has been driving me crazy, I can't find a solution that works!
I'm trying to do a regex between a couple of tags, bad idea I've heard but necessary this time :P
What I have at the start is a `<body class="foo">` where foo can vary between files - `<body.*?>` search works fine to locate the only copy in each file.

At the end I have a `<div id="bar">`, bar doesn't change between files.

eg.

```
<body class="foo">
sometext
some more text
<maybe even some tags>
<div id="bar">
```

What I need to do is select everything between the two tags but not including them - everything between the closing > on body and the opening < on div - sometext to maybe even some tags.

I've tried a bunch of things, mostly variations on `(?<=<body.*>)(.*?)(?=<div id="bar">)` but I'm actually getting invalid expressions at worst on notepad++, http://regexpal.com/ and no matches at best.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to implement variable-length lookbehind in which most regular expression languages and notepad++ does not support. I assume you are using notepad++ so you can use the `\K` escape sequence.

```
<body[^>]*>\K.*?(?=<div id="bar">)
```

The `\K` escape sequence resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included. Make sure you have the `.` matches newline checkbox checked as well.

Alternatively, you can use a capturing group and avoid using lookaround assertions.

```
<body[^>]*>(.*?)<div id="bar">
```

**Note**: Using a capturing group, you can refer to group index "1" to get your match result.

Comment: Thanks for your input :) Unfortunately this is also grabbing the `<body>` and `<div>` tags. I might be a little out of my depth getting it to ignore those, I don't suppose you'd know a solution?

Comment: At the moment i'm using notepad++ on win and http://regexpal.com/ to test. Both grabbed the tags :/

Answer (score 1):

Use the following pattern:

```
/<body[^>]*>(.*?)<div id="bar">/
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply! Unfortunately this is grabbing nothing in notepad++, on regexpal.com it grabs nothing unless I remove the '/' marks, then it grabs the outer tags I was trying to avoid grabbing.

Comment: @user891141 I assumed that you were working in JavaScript. `/pattern/` is the default method of depicting a regex pattern in JS. As for grabbing the `body` and `div` tags, I think that you are confusing __grabbing__ with __grouping__.

Comment: Quite possibly was confusing my terms :P Thanks again for your input :)